# Hiding the Restful service from Webservice list(Apache CXF)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I am working with Apache CXF Framework in which I have specified the Restful as well as the Soap Webservice in cxf-servlet.xml,After Deploying the project and requesting the service list by url as htt://SystemIP:8080/WebServicesExample/services/ the service list appears which has both the SOAP and REST Services,Is there any way to hide the REST Services listed from the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had done it myself...
The simple thing is to add a  property tag to

```
     <jaxrs:properties>
             <entry key="org.apache.cxf.endpoint.private" value="true"/>
     </jaxrs:properties>
```

This is applicable for JAX-WS Service also..This has to be added in cxf-servlet.xml file